# Shapeless' Lazy and default parameters cause implicit resolution to fail

Tags: scala, shapeless

One of my projects uses a mix of scala features that appear to not mix well together:

- type classes, and shapeless automated type class instance derivation
- implicit conversion (to add useful syntax to types that have type class instances)
- default parameters, because even though they're usually a bad thing they're just too convenient here

The problem I'm running into is type class instance derivation fails if either:

- default parameters are not explicitly specified
- shapeless derivation uses `Lazy`

Here's the smallest possible amount of code I could write to reproduce the issue:

### Show.scala

```
import shapeless._

trait Show[A] {
  def show(a: A): String
}

object Show {
  def from[A](f: A => String): Show[A] = new Show[A] {
    override def show(a: A) = f(a)
  }

  implicit val intShow: Show[Int] = Show.from(_.toString)

  implicit def singletonShow[A](implicit
    sa: Show[A]
  ): Show[A :: HNil] = Show.from { 
    case (a :: HNil) => sa.show(a)
  }

  implicit def singletonCaseClassShow[A, H <: HList](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, H],
    sh: Lazy[Show[H]]
  ): Show[A] = Show.from {
    a => sh.value.show(gen.to(a))
  }
}
```

### Run.scala

```
object Run extends App {
  implicit class ShowOps[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal {
    def show(header: String = "> ")(implicit sa: Show[A]): String =
      header + sa.show(a)
  }

  case class Foo(i: Int)

  println(Foo(12).show())
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error message:

```
Run.scala:10: could not find implicit value for parameter sa: Show[Run.Foo]
[error]   println(Foo(12).show())
```

The compilation error is fixed by either:

- explicitly passing a `header` parameter to `show` in `Run.scala`
- removing the `Lazy` wrapper to the implicit `Show[H]` in `Show.scala`

I must admit I'm at a complete loss here. I'd love to understand what happens, and I'd love to know of a workaround if one exists.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer:**

If you move the context bound to the implicit class, it also works fine. You have to sacrifice the value class to do it, but I think it's also cleaner to tell the compiler up front that only `A`s which have a `Show` will get enriched by it:

```
implicit class Show2Ops[A : Show](a: A) {
  def show2(header: String = "> ") = header + implicitly[Show[A]].show(a)
}

println(Foo(12).show2())
```

**Long theory:**

`Lazy` does some interesting tricks, which are hard to follow. You didn't specifically ask about what `Lazy` is doing, but I was curious about it, since I use it all the time without being sure how it works. So I took a look at it. As near as I can tell, it goes something like this.

You have a case class with a recursive field:

```
case class A(first: Int, next: Option[A])
```

And assume you had another case in `Show`'s companion for `Option`:

```
implicit def opt[A](implicit showA: Show[A]): Show[Option[A]] = Show.from {
  case Some(a) => s"Some(${showA.show(a)})"
  case None => "None"
}
```

And instead of `singletonShow` you had a real `HNil` case and an inductive case, as is typical:

```
implicit val hnil: Show[HNil] = Show.from(_ => "")
implicit def hcons[H, T <: HList](implicit
  showH: Show[H],
  showT: Show[T]
): Show[H :: T] = Show.from {
  case h :: t => showH(h) + ", " + showT(t) // for example
}
```

And let's rename `singletonCaseClassShow` to `genericShow` because it's not just for singletons anymore.

Now let's say you didn't have the `Lazy` there in `genericShow`. When you try to summon a `Show[A]`, the compiler goes to:

1. `genericShow[A]` with open implicit search for `Show[A]`
2. `hcons[Int :: Option[A] :: HNil]` with open implicit search for `Show[A]` and `Show[Int :: Option[A] :: HNil`
3. `intShow` with open implicit search for `Show[A]` and `Show[Int]` and `Show[Option[A] :: HNil]`
4. `hcons[Option[A] :: HNil]` with open implicit search for `Show[A]` and `Show[Option[A] :: HNil]`
5. `opt[A]` with open implicit search for `Show[A]` and `Show[Option[A]]` and `Show[Option[A] :: HNil]`
6. `genericShow[A]` with open implicit search for `Show[A]` and `Show[Option[A]]` and `Show[Option[A] :: HNil]`

Now it's pretty clear that there's a problem, because it's going to go back to #2 and happen all over again, never making any progress.

How `Lazy` overcomes this is by going into a macro at the time the compiler attempts to materialize an implicit instance of it. So when you use `implicit showH: Lazy[Show[H]]` in `hcons` instead of just `Show[H]`, the compiler goes to that macro to find `Lazy[Show[H]]` instead of staying in your implicit `Show` cases.

The macro checks the open implicits (which macros helpfully have access to) and goes into its own implicit resolution algorithm that always fully resolves open implicits before continuing with finding the implicit instance of `T` (for `Lazy[T]`). If it comes to resolving an implicit that's already open, it substitutes a dummy tree (essentially telling the compiler "I got this, don't worry about it") that tracks the knotted dependencies so that the rest of the resolution can finish. And at the end, it cleans up the dummy trees (I can't quite figure out how this works; there's a surprising amount of code there and it's pretty complicated!)

So why does `Lazy` seem to mess up your default parameter situation? I think it's the confluence of a few things (only a hypothesis):

1. With your original `ShowOps`, calling `.show` on a value causes a it to be implicitly wrapped in `ShowOps[A]`. What is A going to be? Is it going to be `Foo`, `AnyRef`, `Any`? Is it going to be a unique single type? It's not exactly clear, because at that time there is no constraint on `A` and Scala doesn't know that your call to `.show` will actually constraint it (due to the context bound).
2. Without `Lazy`, this works out OK, because if Scala chooses the wrong `A` and `.show` doesn't typecheck, it will realize its mistake and back out of the `A` it chose.
3. With `Lazy`, there is a bunch of other logic going on, and it kind of tricks Scala into thinking that whatever `A` it chose is fine. But when it comes time to close the loop, it doesn't work out, and by that time it's too late to back out.
4. Somehow, the default parameter being unspecified influences Scala's initial choice for choosing `A` in `ShowOps[A]`.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to just comment to say thanks, but this was properly amazing. I'm in awe.